# R fa.parallel Scree Plot: Limit Plot Range

Tags: r, range

I am doing an Exploratory Factor Analysis over a dataset containing 168 variables. With the fa.parallel()-function I get the answer of how many factors I am supposed to test for. However, I am not happy with the resulting scree plot, which drops off within the first ten or so factors and then flatlines until 168. Is there a way to tell the function to only draw up the scree plot for up to, say, 20 factors, so I can analyse what the graph looks like in the range I'm interested in?[image: My (ugly) Scree Plot]

I looked into the documentation and found n.iter, but that seems to do something else, because setting it to 20 didn't really do anything.